# Caching Url without explicit declaration in dynamicUrlToDependencies using sw-precache

Tags: service-worker, sw-precache

Is there a way, using `sw-precache`, to cache the url you are currently on without exactly specifying the url string in `dynamicUrlToDependencies`? My page caches when I supply a specific relative url `/dynamic/url-circle`, but not if I supply just `/`. I'm assuming this happens because my url is http://localhost:3000/dynamic/url-circle, and not just http://localhost:3000/. I would need this to work for any url string as I would not know the exact url after `dynamic/` (ex. `/dynamic/url-triangle`, `/dynamic/url-square`). Are there any abstractions or a string patterns to use for `dynamicUrlToDependencies`? Or is there a different solution I can use?

ex:

```
    dynamicUrlToDependencies: {
       '/dynamic/url-circle': [ 'public/dist/css/dynamic.css', 'public/dist/js/dynamic.js' ],
       '/': [ 'public/dist/css/dynamic.css', 'public/dist/js/dynamic.js' ],
  },
```

Here is are my `sw-precache` settings in my Gruntfile:

```
   const rootDir = 'public'

   const config = {
       cacheId: version,
       handleFetch: true,
       logger: grunt.log.writeln,
       staticFileGlobs: [
         `${rootDir}/dist/js/*.{css,js}`,
         `${rootDir}/dist/css/*.{css,js}`,
         `${rootDir}/dist/offline.html`,
       ],
       dynamicUrlToDependencies: {
          '/dynamic/url-circle': [ 'public/dist/css/dynamic.css', 'public/dist/js/dynamic.js' ],
          '/': [ 'public/dist/css/dynamic.css', 'public/dist/js/dynamic.js' ],
       },
       stripPrefix: `${rootDir}/`,
       directoryIndex: 'dist/offline.html',
       navigateFallback: 'dist/offline.html',
       verbose: true,
       maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 15 * 1024 * 1024, // 15MB
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `runtimeCaching` to cache your page. I did something like this.

```
  runtimeCaching: [
      urlPattern: /\/url-lot\//,
      handler: 'networkFirst',
    },
  ]
```

and then every url with `url-lot` in it would be cached.
Feels a bit obvious now, but that's life.